# OpenCV 3.1 Android minimum requirements

Tags: android, c++, opencv, requirements

I have an application that uses OpenCV 3.1, and I'm having an issue when trying to download the app from Play Store, it isn't compatible with a device. I've found that this version of OpenCV is what causing it, once that I used to use version 2.4.1 (no more allowed for security issues) and deploying without the part that uses OpenCV is compatible. Searching in OpenCV documentation, I can't find anything about this!

Comment: what is your android version ?

Comment: @PavneetSingh my android version is 5.1 (API 22). I'm able to deploy the application by Android Studio without crashes, only can't find it on store